# Changing background color of a cell in a datagrid when its value changes

Tags: c#, wpf, serial-port

I have a Datagrid, with one column being populated by values coming in from a serial port.
Just need to change background color of a cell if its value is different from the previous value.
Column -- Value1 has serial data coming in.
inbuffer[] stores the serial values which are then displayed in column -- Value1.

cs#:

```
Display_group0 Display_grp = new Display_group0();
    public class Display_group0 : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private bool _Value_changed;
        public bool Value_changed {
            get { return _Value_changed; }
            set {
                _Value_changed = value;
                if (PropertyChanged != null)
                {
                    PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Value_changed"));
                }
            }
        }
    }
this.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
                {
                    // Change the inbuffer number accordingly
                    List<User> items = new List<User>();
                    if{}
                    else      // in normal course display only default values in the last column of list view.
                    {
                        this.Data_grid.Columns[4].Header = "Default Value";
                        for (int i = 0; i < Current_grp.Length; i++)   // loop for all parameters of a group. .length indicates length of an array which is the group.
                        {
                            if (condition to check change in value)
                            {
                                Display_grp.Value_changed = true;  // indicates a value change     
                            }
                            items.Add(new User() { Display1 = Current_grp[i].Para_number, Parameter1 = Current_grp[i].Para_name, Range1 = Current_grp[i].Range, Value1 = Convert.ToString(Decimal.Round(((decimal)((inbuffer[(4 * i) + 4]) | (inbuffer[(4 * i) + 3]) << 8 | (inbuffer[(4 * i) + 5]) << 24 | (inbuffer[(4 * i) + 6]) << 16) / Current_grp[i].Scale), Current_grp[i].Dec_place)), File_Value1 = Convert.ToString(Decimal.Round(((decimal)(Current_grp[i].Default) / Current_grp[i].Scale), Current_grp[i].Dec_place)) });
                        }
                    }
                    Data_grid.ItemsSource = items;

<DataGrid x:Name="Data_grid" Height="1" Margin="0,5,0,-25" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1150" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellEditEnding="CellEditEnding" SelectionMode="Single" Visibility="Hidden">
                            <DataGrid.Columns>
                                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Display"  Width="100" Binding="{Binding Display1}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
                                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Parameter" Width="250" Binding="{Binding Parameter1}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
                                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Range1}" Header="Range" Width="200" IsReadOnly="True"/>
                                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Value1, ValidatesOnExceptions=True}"  Header="Drive value" Width="150" IsReadOnly="True">
                                    <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                                            <Style.Triggers>
                                                <DataTrigger x:Name="Value_change" Value="true" Binding="{Binding Value_changed, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
                                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow"></Setter>
                                                </DataTrigger>
                                            </Style.Triggers>
                                        </Style>
                                    </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                                </DataGridTextColumn>                                    
                                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding File_Value1}" Header="File value" Width="150" IsReadOnly="True"/>
                            </DataGrid.Columns>
                        </DataGrid>
```

Comment: So what's the issue? Doesn't the `DataTrigger` work as expected or what happens?

Comment: And what's the puspose of the `Display_group0` class? Isn't the `ItemsSource` set to a `List<User>`!?

Comment: Data trigger doesn't work. Value_changed is a property of Display_group0 and is used to trigger a change in background.Also checked that Value_changed = true when value changes. Is there a problem in the xaml part?

Comment: Yes, because it seems there is no `Value_change` property to bind to in the `User` class.

Comment: Where is `Display_group0` supposed to be used...?

Comment: Sorry. Could you suggest a modification?

Comment: See my answer. Get rid of the `Display_group0` class.

Answer (score 0):

Since you set the `ItemsSource` of the `DataGrid` to a `List<User>`, you should move the `Value_changed` property to the `User` class for this binding to work:

```
<DataTrigger Value="true" Binding="{Binding Value_changed, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow" />
</DataTrigger>
```

It's unclear what the `Display_group0` class is for. The `DataContext` of the element in the column in the `DataGrid` is the current `User` object and nothing else.